# eclipse - how to set search view to show the result in a list instead of a tree view

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to get each item listed individually, sorted by file name? someone could manage to do that - but no details how
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000MMPaIAO

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the small triangle at the top right of the Search view and select 'Show as List'.

Comment: ok, i was looking for this settings for hours.. thanks! even I started with that small triangle - can not believe this..

Comment: This desired view only shows the filename, is it a joke? I need a grep like result without tree arrangement.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a 'grep like result'. This list matches what you referenced in your question and is all that the Search view will show in the List format.

Comment: with this list view only filename and their locations are listed. I want to see the matched line as well. and if more then one matches in the same file should be listed not just mentioning that there is X matches in the file

Comment: Agree with @HiB. Many IDEs and Editors provide awesome "grep like" view of the results with each match on the separate line: <file> <line> <match>. This is available in Vim, Notepad++, etc... and is very useful if the number of results per file is larger than numer of lines dedicated for the search window. If it's larger I personally find it quite impractical to scroll a few pages just to find the file name of the matched phrase.